# best practices in naming session variables

Tags: php, session

I was used to naming my session variables the "normal" way, kinda like when I want to keep track of user details, I name them:

- `$_SESSION['username']`
- `$_SESSION['email']`
- `$_SESSION['id']`

I am worried that they may be in conflict with other session data when I am browsing sites in the same browser, or will there not be any conflict at all(once I tried to simultaneously run two of my projects with the same session variables, residing in the same server, and obviously, things got real messy).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All of the session data is stored on the server. All the browser has is a cookie that references the session on the server. There can't be naming conflicts for this reason, and also because Cookies naming scope is domain based.

Comment: I just wanted to write a mad reply, but then realized that you got it right. That's what he wanted to know. +1

Answer (score 2):

Consider setting them in a subarray related to your application:

```
$_SESSION['myapp']['username']
$_SESSION['myapp']['id']
```

That should significantly help avoid conflicts.

EDIT: I misread your question, Luca Matteis has your answer.  My solution above would be to avoid your multiple apps on the same domain session conflict.

Comment: Didn´t know we could do that. Thanks. Normally, I would create a prefix for the app and mix in.